# javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException instead of the actual exception in Jersey Exception Mapper

Tags: java, jersey

Why do I always get javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException instead of the actual exception class in my Exception Mapper:

```
@Provider
public class PaymentExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    /*
     * Maps the Exception object to response Object when any exception is thrown
     * within the application.
     */
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(550)
                .entity(exception)
                .build();
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is already answered, I couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register this `PaymentExceptionHandler` as jersey resource for jersey container to understand that this response needs to be sent in case `Exception` class is sent in the response.

Like throw `new RunTimeExecption(e)`, jersey will throw `PaymentExceptionHandler` in response.

Load your `PaymentExceptionHandler` as a jersey resource.

I don't know how have you loaded your resources through package scan or some other way, one way to do this is shown below:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class AuthResourceLoader extends Application
{
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.ws.rs.core.Application#getClasses()
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        exceptionResource(classes);
        return classes;
    }

    private void exceptionResource(Set<Class<?>> classes)
    {
        classes.add(PaymentExceptionHandler.class);
    }
}
```